# Drawing switching circuit in LaTeX?

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I want to draw the following switching circuit?

[image]

After googling I have found the link[here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuit-decorations/), but I can not able to draw the required diagram.

**Updated :**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

% modified code from pgfcircbipoles.sty and circuitikz1.code.tex

\makeatletter
% create the shape
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/interr/height 2}}{spst}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/interr/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/interr/width}}{

    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}   
}

% make the shape accessible with nice syntax
\def\pgf@circ@spst@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{spst}{#1}}
\tikzset{switch/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@spst@path, l=#1}}
\tikzset{spst/.style = {switch = #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[switch, l=$t_0$] (2,0)
                to[spst] (2,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE), not not just a fragment. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple Ti*k*Z proposal using only lines and nodes.

Each switch is constructed by connecting the `north` and `east` coordinates of the `node`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (0,0)--++(1,0) coordinate (P0) --++(0,1)--++(0.5,0) node [right,inner sep=6pt] (X1) {$x$};
  \draw (X1.north)--(X1.east)--++(1,0) coordinate (P1) --++(0,0.5)--++(0.5,0) node [right,inner sep=6pt] (Y1) {$y$};
  \draw (Y1.north)--(Y1.east)--++(0.5,0)--++(0,-0.5) coordinate (P2) --++(0,-0.5) --++(-0.5,0) node [left,inner sep=6pt] (Z1) {$z$} -- (Z1.north);
  \draw (Z1.west)--++(-0.5,0)--(P1);
  \draw (P2)--++(0.5,0)--++(0,-1) coordinate (P3) --++(1,0);
  \draw (P3)--++(0,-1) --++(-1,0) coordinate (Z2end) node [left,inner sep=6pt] (Z2) {$z$} --(Z2.north);
  \draw (Z2.west)--++(-1.5,0) node [left,inner sep=6pt] (Y2) {$y$} --(Y2.north);
  \draw (Y2.west)-|(P0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

with `circuitikz`, exploiting all its possibilities (to my opinion with more correct labeling of switches):

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0)   -| ++ (1, 1)
                to [nos,l=$x$] ++ (2,0) coordinate (x)
                -- ++ (0,0.5)
                to [nos,l=$y$] ++ (2,0)
                |- ++ (0.5,-0.5) |- ++ (1,-1)
        (x)     -- ++ (0,-0.5)
                to [nos,l=$z$] ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,0.5)
        (0,0)   -| ++ (1,-1)
                to [nos,l=$y$] ++ (2,0)
                to [nos,l=$z$] ++ (2,0) -| ++ (0.5,1)
                ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
a little bit modified code (which should enable more easy to extend to other switches topology) and add some "fancy" connection points:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   % in
        (0,0)   to [short,o-*]      ++ (1,0)    coordinate (in)
                -- ++ (0, 1)
                to [nos,l=$x$,-*]   ++ (2,0)    coordinate (x)
        % upper branch
                -- ++ (0,0.5)
                to [nos,l=$y$]  ++ (2,0)
                to [short,-*]   ++ (0,-0.5)       
                -| ++ (0.5,-1)                  coordinate (out)
        (x)     -- ++ (0,-0.5)
                to [nos,l=$z$]  ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,0.5)
        % lower branch
        (in)   -- ++ (0,-1)
                to [nos,l=$y$]  ++ (2,0)
                to [nos,l=$z$]  ++ (2,0) -| (out)
        % out
                to[short,*-o]    ++ (1,0)
                ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A starting point with the `circuitikz` package

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[color=black, thick] (2,0) -- (4,0) ;
\draw[color=black, thick] (4,-1) -- (4,1) ;
\draw (4,1) to[normal open switch, *-*] (5,1);% Does not work node[pos=0.5,below]{y};
\path (4,1) -- (5,1) node[pos=0.5,below]{x};
\draw (4,-1) to[normal open switch, *-*] (5,-1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]